# Conditionally Save responses to a file based on HTTP code or body string

Tags: jmeter

I'm a newbie in using Jmeter and searching for a solution solving the following problem: I have a suite that contains a set of atomic HTTP requests and the goal is to save response bodies into an xml file. Currently, I'm handling that with using "Save Responses to a file listener", but need to be able to save separately error and OK responses in different XML, based on response HTTP code and body string.

to illustrate the case with dummy code

```
if (HTTP response code == 200 OK && body does not contain "ERROR") then
     save response to file (%path%\responsename_OK.xml
else
     save response to file (%path%\responsename_ERROR.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, Nikolay, I forgot you wanted it in xml format...

Well, the **easiest** way is to add 2 Simple Data Writers (SDW) to each HTTP Request where 1 SDW logs only errors and the other logs only successes.

[image]

[image]

The Pro's are

- it's easy and once you set it up for 1 HTTP Request, you can simply copy it to every other HTTP Request
- Each success or failure with be appended to the corresponding .xml file
- You can define as much or as little detail as you want

The Con is you add 2 elements to each Request, thus increasing your test size twice as much as you would with a BeanShell Assertion. (*if that's a concern for you*.)

If you want a more detailed way, you could try a BeanShell Assertion scripted with XML Parsers and XPath Assertions like outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028596/looping-through-data-in-jmeter-and-storing-data-to-use-in-other-sampler).

Comment: so simple, that is too hard to come in mind. Thanks David, that completely works for me for now

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) (in fact you will need 2: one for Response Code and another one for Response Body checking) in order to fail the request basing on these criteria
2. Use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) for setting a condition:

   - `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` will be triggered if previous sampler is successful
   - `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` - will fire if previous sampler fails

     N.B. you should have any Sampler under the If Controller so it could work.

Comment: Dmitri, does that you propose solves the goal to put into account also extracted result from the response body? Currently with David solution, the result is based on HTTP Code returned, but I need to go further with adding response body.