# Jmeter code to read response xml attributes in beanshell post processor without using Xpath Extractor?

Tags: jmeter

Below mentioned XML is a sample xml, like this there are 'N' number of nodes available and I want to read XML attribute in Beanshell post processor. I get this XML from the HTTP request. How to read that XML (HTTP Response) in Jmeter beanshell post processor like we read in java?

```
 <Order OrderNo="Y1101001">
     <OrderLines>
       <OrderLine LineNo="1" LineKey="20171100011"> 
       <OrderLine LineNo="2" LineKey="20171100012">
      </OrderLines>
     </Order>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find beanshell/java code to extract values from xml:

[Looping through data in JMeter and storing data to use in other sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028596/looping-through-data-in-jmeter-and-storing-data-to-use-in-other-sampler)

Answer (score 2):

Beanshell is more or less Java compatible, therefore you can use plain [Java code to parse XML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html).

However I would recommend considering [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead, Groovy is better from performance point of view, moreover it has built-in XML support so you will be able to get the count of your `OrderLine` elements as simple as:

```
def response = new XmlParser().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString()) 
def size = response.OrderLines.OrderLine.size()
log.info("Size: " + size)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSR223 XML]

References:

- [Groovy - Processing XML](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)